# How can I add a @media query through the chrome inspector?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

If I  do `@media(min-width: 375px)` in the chrome inspector it drops my code as soon as I try to enter the body to define more of the rule.

[image: Trying to add a media query using the chrome inspector]

Is it possible to add @media rules through the inspector?

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) in JavaScript, @media can be accessed via the CSS object model interface `CSSMediaRule`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks as though the Styles editor panel doesn't support adding `@media` rules. However, you can get around this by clicking on the `inspector-stylesheet` link to open it in the Sources panel. It is then possible to enter your `@media` query and the changes will be reflected immediately.

[image: inspector-stylesheet]

[image: inspector-stylesheet editing]

You can consequently see it in the Styles panel afterwards and modify the rule and CSS properties inline. It is just the initial creation that it doesn't support.

[image: Styles panel]